# Phillips–Perron unit root test instead of ADF test?

Tags: regression, cointegration

I have read that PP unit root is often used in economy. Is it sensible to do both tests (PP & ADF) or is PP test enough?

Comment: assume they give different results (i mean in terms of p-value), how do you plan to interpret this? Then what if they give the same result?

Comment: @user603 i don't understand your answer. I mean that reading some economy book i found that PP test is often used, so my questions are: is there a sense to use ADF? do i have to use both? is PP enough?

Comment: sorry missunderstood your question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A great **advantage** of [Philips-Perron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phillips%E2%80%93Perron_test) test is that it is *non-parametric*, i.e. it does not require to select the level of serial correlation as in ADF. It rather takes the same estimation scheme as in DF test, but corrects the statistic to conduct for autocorrelations and heteroscedasticity (HAC type corrections).

The main **disadvantage** of the PP test is that it is based on asymptotic theory. Therefore it works well only in large samples that are indeed luxury if not it comes for financial time series data. And it also shares disadvantages of ADF tests: sensitivity to structural breaks, poor small sample power too often resulting in unit root conclusions.

It is **advisable** to make several tests and see if the results match, if not check the properties of the time series (PP is more robust to deviations from "gentleman's" set of properties!). You may also consider Zivot-Andrew test if you believe the data has structural breaks.

I have found this lecture notes [Unit Root Testing To Help Model Building](http://www.bankofengland.co.uk/education/ccbs/handbooks/pdf/ccbshb22.pdf) by L. Mahadeva and P.Robinson useful to answer the questions. May be it will give more information to you.

Comment: "it does not require a priori information regarding the functional form of the residuals" I understand what you mean, but this wording can be misleading: usually it is (and arguably should be) taken in a  the sense of distribution freeness of the test statistics (as in say, http://arno.uvt.nl/show.cgi?fid=113569 ). It could be a good idea to reformulate this statement a bit to avoid any possible confusion.

Comment: @Dimitrij thank you! Your answers are very apprecially. Before start to read the link you posted, as far I have perfecty understand I think there is not a "perfect" method to do this check (I always referring to financial time series data). Also zivot is good to know if there are breaks inside the series, btw, if you have two series (financial) what is the first (unit root) method you try? :-) thanks!

Comment: @user603, may be such correction is more suitable? I indeed tried to say it does not require hyper-parameters like the lag length for autoregressive polynomial to be pre-specified. I usually prefer KPSS to ADF and PP. For large scale data KPSS and PP should provide similar conclusions, but will suffer from the structural breaks.

Comment: @ Dmitrij Celov: it is your answer, not mine, but the wiki link you provide has a nice, unambiguous formulation [emphasize mine]: "the Phillips–Perron test makes a non-parametric *correction* to the t-test statistic. The test is robust with respect to *unspecified autocorrelation and heteroscedasticity in the disturbance process of the test equation.*" Here it is clear that the functional form of the residuals is assumed Gaussian, yet allowing for varying (but stationnary) auto-correlation and variance.

Comment: @Dmitrij Celov: do you prefer KPSS instead of ADF and PP? Can you tell me why? can I use this method and maybe Zivot-Andrew for breaks, what do you thinks?

Comment: @user603 thank you for your answers, but i don't understand if you prefer one method instead of another. Could you explain this? thanks

Comment: @Dail: Its not about the answer, it's about the formulation. I may be wrong on this, but i have the impression that most people, upon reading 'assumes no functional form of the residuals of a variable' will not think it to mean that PP assumes (as it does) that the innovations are Gaussian....I, for one, find that the way it i formulated on wikipedia is much less ambiguous.

Comment: KPSS is a bit more powerful in small samples, in large ones as for financial data you may take PP as well. (+1) to @user603 comment, will try to learn at last to be more correct in statements, but I think it is nothing really to do with Gaussian distribution, it's just requires i.i.d with two finite moments, and then you may apply CLT. I may be wrong however.

Comment: @Dmitrij Celov what do you mean with "small samples" (and large) ? Can we talk about the number? 100? 1000? thank you very much!

Comment: Roughly small is less than 50 and it is common in macro-econometrics. With daily (or even more frequent intra-day) financial data you will have thousands of observations.

Comment: @Dmitrij Celov I'm a bit confused... in your second comment you wrote: "For large scale data KPSS and PP should provide similar conclusions", so why i should use KPSS for small and PP for large? thank you for the clarification

Comment: Since both test rely on asymptotic results in the limit there is little difference between KPSS, PP and ADF conclusions regarding unit roots. PP is advisable in the presence of heteroscedasticity though. In Kwiatkovski et al. article it was argued that KPSS works better within the small samples (if I am not mistaken their first experiment was with sample 50). Note that in KPSS the authors switched the null and alternative, they focused on stationarity.

Comment: Hi, I know that this was posted a whileeeeeee ago, but I would greatly appreciate your help. What do you exactly mean that a great advantage of Philips-Perron test is that it is non-parametric, i.e. it does not require to select the level of serial correlation as in ADF? When should I use PP vs. ADF?

Comment: @DmitrijCelov: Your second paragraph is important to underscore. Here is a quote from Davidson & Mackinnon (page 623): "... there is now a good deal of evidence that PP tests perform less well [than ADF tests] in finite samples... "

Answer (score 2):

Generally, Adf test is used when the errors are homoscedastic and PP test is preferred for hetroscedastic errors.