# What are the assumptions for checking the stationarity of a time series?

Tags: r, time-series, stationarity, augmented-dickey-fuller, kpss-test

I am checking stationarity or non-stationarity of a time series with R and I am using `adf.test` and `kpss.test` in `tseries` package.

What are the assumptions for these tests?
Is following a Gaussian distribution by the data set one of the assumption?
If yes, what can we do for non-Gaussian time series?

Also, is using the default options for lag order in ADF which is $k = \text{trunc}((\text{length}(x)-1)^{1/3})$ a safe assumption?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADF is a parametric test and KPSS is a non-parametric test of unit root. That being said, the chosen lag order in the ADF should be such that residuals are white noise.

Comment: So it means for KPSS normal distribution is not a assumption but for ADF is?

Comment: you can find more on that here : `http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14076/phillipsperron-unit-root-test-instead-of-adf-test`

Comment: @ user1493368 your answer was very helpful for me but Still I am not sure if ADF requires a specific distribution for the data. However I accepted the answer and Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ Fred : ADF assumes the error term of AR(p) process to be white noise which is a less strong assumption than Gaussian noise. I therefore think that normality is not a requirement. KPSS doesn't assumes the error term to be white noise.

Comment: Glad that I was able to help you.