# About the stationarity of a sine wave

Tags: r, time-series, cointegration, unit-root, stationarity

I generated two sine wave time series and want to check the stationarity of them.

[image]

(1) The first time series is short. `kpss.test()` thinks it is stationary. `PP.test()` doesn't reject the null of unit root.

```
n=120
t=1:n
x=sin(t/(n-1)*6*pi)+rnorm(n)*0.2
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
plot(x,ty='l',xlab='',ylab='x',main='Sine')

# stationary test (H0:stationary)
kpss.test(x)$p.value
#[1] 0.1

# unit root test (H0: unit root)
PP.test(x)$p.value
#[1] 0.4937582
```

(2) The second one is much longer. `kpss.test()` says it is non-stationary while `PP.test()` tells it is stationary.

```
n=1000
t=1:n
x=sin(t/(n-1)*6*pi)+rnorm(n)*0.2
plot(x,ty='l',xlab='',ylab='x',main='Sine')

# stationary test (H0:stationary)
kpss.test(x)$p.value
#[1] 0.01

# unit root test (H0: unit root)
PP.test(x)$p.value
#[1] 0.01
```

While `kpss.test()` is more powerful for small samples ([please see this Q&A](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14076/phillipsperron-unit-root-test-instead-of-adf-test)), the first instance is understandable. However, I am really confused why `kpss.test()` fails for the second larger-sample time series. Anyone have any comments or answers please?

Comment: a sine wave is not stationary but unless I missed something, I don't think it has a unit root (which is a particular kind of nonstationarity). But in any case, failure to find a unit root doesn't imply stationarity.

Answer (score 5):

We can classify trend part of time series in two parts: 1) Deterministic; 2) Stochastic. Most of the tests around stationarity is to test the unit root (deterministic trend).

In your case it is clearly deterministic trend. The trend part one can write as a function of time. Regarding the kpss test, null hypothesis of kpss test is **the series is level or trend stationary**. Kpss test accept H0 in your case. (In your second case, if you increase your frequency the test may fail to rejct the H0, `x=sin(t/(n-1)*60*pi)+rnorm(n)*0.2`).

Usually in time series modelling  first step is to eliminate (remove or by adding deterministic part) deterministic part in the time series. So practically this cases will not arise.

Comment: Surely you meant that the tests for stationarity test for stochastic trend?

Comment: @mpiktas, let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: Well the tests for stationarity usually test or test against unit root, hence stochastic trend, not deterministic.

Comment: Agreed. I will add this and avoid the confusion.

Comment: I agree with @mpiktas that unit root test is for stochastic trend. But the null hypothesis of kpss test if level or trend stationary. The 'Trend' here means linear trend instead of any deterministic trend.

Comment: Yes when the frequency increases to some extent, both tests will say it is stationary. The question is the two plots above have the same frequency, but they are not the same regarding stationarity. The only difference is their sample numbers.

Comment: don't get confused by the my mention about frequency.  In first kpss is failed to reject null (pvalue >0.05). In  second case I guess it is because of large data it not giving the right conclusion.

Comment: @vinux But in the second case if I twice the frequency with the length of time series unchanged, I get $p>0.05$.

Comment: If you increase the frequency, I guess the test is able to account the seasonal pattern (deterministic trend).

Comment: @vinux doesn't kpss test only recognise linear trend?

Comment: I am not sure about the theory behind kpss test. I rarely used this test. I guess experts in this forum can help you on this.

Answer (score 4):

The [Kwiatkowski–Phillips–Schmidt–Shin 1992 paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/030440769290104Y#) proved an influential contribution to time-series analysis, because it was the first well-recognized test that tested for non-stationarity by taking as null-hypothesis that the series is (linear determinisitic) trend-stationary -contrary to the Dickey-Fuller (or Phillips-Peron) family of tests that have as null that a unit root exists (i.e. that the series contains a stochastic trend).

The reasoning behind the KPSS  test is that unit-root tests of the DF/PP variety have low power especially when the root may be close to but below unity.  Most researchers advise that one should run both kinds of tests, and if they give conflicting results as regards the kind of trend detected, one should conclude that the data are not informative enough to provide an answer.

In the original KPSS test, a time series is modeled as being comprised of a linear deterministic trend, a random walk (the stochastic trend), and a white noise:

$$y_t = at+r_t+u_t, \qquad r_t=r_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t,\; \\u_t, \varepsilon_t\sim\operatorname{white noise and independent}$$

The null hypothesis is that $$\operatorname{Var}(\varepsilon_t)=0$$
which effectively eliminates the existence of the random walk (since it turns it into a constant, supplying the series with a drift). Under this null, the time-series is trend-stationary (i.e. it is stationary around a linear deterministic trend).
The test can also be used to test level-stationarity by not including the deterministic-trend part in the specification.
Under the additional assumption of normally distributed $\varepsilon_t$, the test statistic is a one-sided Lagrange Multiplier one. If the normality assumption is dropped, and if we further weaken the white-noise assumption and assume that $\{\varepsilon_t\}$ forms a mixing process, then the test-statistic has a non-standard distribution, which has special critical values.

As for a sine wave, does it look like it may contain a linear deterministic trend? **Seasonality** is what happens here. One of the original authors of the KPSS test (Peter C.B. Phillips) shows [in this paper](http://korora.econ.yale.edu/phillips/pubs/art/p1132.pdf%E2%80%8E) that the KPSS test statistic has the same limiting distribution when the data exhibit seasonality.

**But here comes the critical point**: the KPSS statistic is based on the residuals of least-squares regression of the dependent variable on a constant and a linear time-trend, *when there is no seasonality*. When there is seasonality, then the test statistic is based on a least-squares regression on a constant and *seasonal dummies* (or other more complicated ways to model seasonality). Does your software know what kind of regression to estimate in order to calculate the KPSS statistic?